# Failed to temporarily disable Foreign Key Checks or Constraints in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I know you can disable foreign key check by set 0 to the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, but in mysql BD with phpmyadmin Version 4.8.5, it does not work for me.

I want to drop the table without checking foreign key constraint

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I expect the query to drop the table, but I got this error.
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: What do you want to do with the "dangling" foreign keys?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45258632) (it is not entirely clear how you are executing your code).

Comment: I want to drop a table that has a link with other tables, setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 does not help, I still got an error that I can not delete it.